# Liferay site specific property

Tags: liferay, portal

I have a requirement where I need to define a site specific property and if the property is present perform certain action.

I do not want to use portal-ext.properties as that is portal wide, what i need is a property that is specific to site.

Any pointers?

Comment: Which version of Liferay are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the properties in some configuration file - you can still use `portal-ext.properties` and add some site specific id to the key:

```
my.property.12048 = The setting for the group (site) with id 12048
```

You can access these from code with `PropsUtil`:

```
String propertyValue = PropsUtil.get("my.property" + group.getGroupId());
```

(You could use other identifiers like the friendly URL as well).

If you like to have an editable value in the UI - you can declare a custom field for a site in the control panel and set the value for each site in the site administration. To access that value from code:

```
String propertyValue = (String) group.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("myCustomFieldName");
```